# UNIX Sendmail Change Sender in Header

Tags: unix, sendmail, hp-ux, mailx

I need to change the "Received: (from pseudouser@**localhost**)" in the email header to "Received: (from pseudouser@**company.com**).  My domain name has already been set in the sendmail.cf, and I've already set masquerade to "company.com."  Any ideas on what I can do to reach my end goal?

**Current Code**

```
cat body.txt | sendmail -s "Request" user@company.com
```

**Email Header**

```
Received: (from pseudouser@localhost)    by servername.corp.company.net (@(#)Sendmail
version 8.13.3 - Revision 1.007 - 3 February 2010/8.11.1) id ####
            for user@company.com; Tue, 23 Jul 2013 14:36:15 -0500 (CDT)
Date: Tue, 23 Jul 2013 14:36:15 -0500
From: pseudouser@company.com
Message-ID: <201307231936.####@servername.corp.company.net>
To: <user@company.com>
Subject: Request
Return-Path: pseudouser@company.com
```

**Set Domain To...**

```
$ sendmail -d0.1 -bv root

Version @(#)Sendmail version 8.13.3 - Revision 1.007 - 3 February 2010

============ SYSTEM IDENTITY (after readcf) ============
      (short domain name) $w = servername
  (canonical domain name) $j = $w.corp.company.net
         (subdomain name) $m = corp.company.net
              (node name) $k = servername
========================================================
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done through the header information of the content text file. Script will be like follows.

Mail sending command

```
cat mail_content.html | /usr/lib/sendmail -t
```

mail_content.html

```
From: donotreply@sample.com
To: info@sample.com
Subject: Subject of the mail
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html

<h1>Sample html body</h1>
```

Here at the "from" attribute you can define the from address.

Answer (score 1):

Try edit  /etc/mail/sendmail.mc

```
MASQUERADE_AS(`yourdomain.com')dnl
```

and run "service sendmail restart"